# Impedance matching for high speed pulse generators

Tags: pulse, impedance-matching

I came across the following article on impedance matching for pulses which have very sharp rising and falling edges:
https://www.avtechpulse.com/appnote/techbrief12/

- They claim that the output impedance of the generator (50 ohm) and the load impedance should be equal
- They assume the pulsers have \$Z_{out}\$ = 50 Ohm Output Impedance

Therefore in the case of a load which is less than 50 ohm, a series resistor needed as shown below:

[image]

Similarly if the load is greater than 50 ohm, a shunt resistor can help as shown below:

[image]

I have three questions regarding this issue:

1. When they make matching why they only take into account the load resistor and series or shunt resistor but not the 50 ohm resistance from the coaxial cable? For example in the first example they set: \$Z_{out} = R_s + R_{load}\$ = 50 ohm. Why do they omit the coaxial cable resistance in this matching?
2. Why would unmatched output impedance and the equivalent load resistance cause ringing or reflections? Is there a way to describe this reason illustratively?
3. Is there a specific reason historically to standardize output impedance 50 ohm in general but not 10 ohm for instance?

Comment: Well, for your 1), I would say they match it correctly. You pass from coaxial cable which have a 50 ohm signal impedance to a load so therefore you want your load to have a 50 ohm too. 2) I am certain you can find the mathematical proof for that. 3) I think it is because of radio or RF but this is just a hypothesis.

Comment: I dont understand isnt that Zout is output impedance? Coaxial is like a series resistor. Im confused

Comment: It isn't a 50 ohm from ohmic resistane. It is a 50 ohm from line impedance. If you take a ohmmeter and measure the resistance, mostly it will be around a very small value because coaxial cable are made of copper. You should check out the lossless line section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_impedance. The impedance of 50 ohms represent the inductive & capacitive parasite in your lines that will result in delay and reflections.

Comment: So do u mean what ever measurement I make with a coax i can neglect its resistance? Even for a pullse at too high freq.?

Comment: You should look Andy's answer. Also, please define "too high frequency".

Comment: like UHF say 2 Ghz

Comment: To do the short version, IRL it is electromagnetic wave who travel down the lines. Current & Voltage are just correct approximation at low frequency because they represent quasi-static case of the Maxwell's equation where the lenght of your cable are negliegeable compare to the wavelenght of your wave. At 2 Ghz, your cable of your generator start to introduce delay and reflection. If you want to avoid reflection you need to match the impedance line in your load.

Comment: Im not talking about reflection Im asking if the amplitude attenuates due to 50 ohm at 2GHz

Comment: If you are using an oscilloscope, no it doesn't matter, you will see when the reflection have fade away if your duty cycle let the reflections fade away. If your pulse are too small and you aren't match, you most likely you will just have enormous transient on your rise and fall.

Comment: @user16307, from a theoretical perspective, the amplitude is not diminished by the characteristic impedance. But as a practical matter, at 2 GHz, all real cables have significant attenuation. You are asking a LOT of questions about a BIG topic. You really need to read about transmission line theory. Start with lossless transmission lines. After you sort of understand that, you can read about skin effect, and dielectric losses in cables.

Comment: To confuse you some more, this type of termination is called parallel (or shunt) termination. A far more common way of doing this is a series termination where you ensure you have driver impedance matching the line impedance, in this case 50 ohm. So you take your driver impedance and add a series resistor to make 50 ohm. It will "consume" the reflection when it reaches the starting point.

Comment: @mkeith I agree, transmission line is a big subject because it is really counter intuitive to what have been teach in quasi-static electrical course.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The characteristic impedance of any cable at high frequencies is determined by the inductance per unit length and the capacitance per unit length. It should not to be regarded as a conventional lossy resistor - characteristic impedance is simply the impedance that the cable should ideally be terminated with to prevent reflections.

So, reflections happen when there is a mismatch between the termination and the cable's characteristic impedance.

Consider a longish piece of coax fed at one end with an instantaneous voltage of 5V. That 5V will take some finite time to travel down to the load (lets say the load is 1 kohm) so it cannot know how much current the load needs. However, the cable "informs" the source how much current to flow - if it's 50 ohm cable then 100 mA will flow. So you have 5 V and 100 mA rapidly travelling down the cable and they reach the load to find that it's 1 kohm.

In other words, too much current is flowing for a 1kohm load with 5V applied. So a reflection occurs to combat the excessive current. After a few cycles of "there and back" things settle down.

Here's a nice picture of a transient wave passing through a mismatch (vertical black line) - note the energy reflected back to the source: -

[image]

Because I'm old and sometimes wise I can tell you that the left half of the cable has a higher characteristic impedance than the right half. There are two clues that tell me this. First clue; the width of the pulse shortens in the right half implying the velocity has dropped as the pulse entered this right hand area, Clue 2; there is a negative voltage reflection.

Now, think about that vertical black line - can you imagine that the black line is a solid wall and you're holding a rope attached to that wall. You wiggle the rope to induce a transient pulse and you'll get a reflection coming back just like the picture above. Same phenomena, same maths.

There are plenty of great pictures on the web that demo this. Here's one that shows how a transmitted square wave becomes misshaped: -

[image]

Note that the "ringing" *does look* like traditional LC type ringing but, if you inspect closely you'll see that they are slightly rounded-off square wave reflections adding and subtracting from what would be the perfect received signal.

Here are two animations of a pulse hitting an open circuit (top) and a pulse hitting a short circuit (bottom). Note the polarity of the reflection heading back to the left: -

[image]

[image]

Regarding the value of 50 ohms, 50 ohms is a compromise between power (power prefers lower impedances) and attenuation characteristics (75 ohms is much preferred to reduce high frequency attenuation).

And finally, the Shive wave machine: -

[image]

You can watch a 30 minute video on youtube that is really great I reckon. It deals with all sorts of reflections and loading effects but uses a mechanical analogy of the transmission line. Video [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DovunOxlY1k)

Comment: Great explanations of the 50 ohms value.

Comment: Do reflections happen due to high freq components of a pulse or due to any freq component?

Comment: Reflections happen at all frequencies but are more obvious to see at higher frequencies. As the cable becomes longer than about one-tenth the wavelength of the signal, "things" start to happen. Clearly at 20 kHz, one wavelength is 15 km so it's pointless trying to see things happening at this low a frequency. At exactly one quarter of one wavelength a short becomes an open circuit and vice versa - there are some strange things happening!

Comment: What ever measurement I make with a coax i can neglect its resistance? Even for a pullse at too high freq.? Or will there be voltage drop accross the coax  for signal at GHz level?

Comment: You can't neglect its resistance if the cable is long - reflections due to mismatches will die out due to losses in the cable (both copper loss and dielectric loss).

Comment: sorry to dig it but you wrote " if it's 50 ohm cable then 100 mA will flow. So you have 5 V and 100 mA rapidly passing down the cable " you first say for the coax " It is not to be regarded as a lossy resistor -" which means it has zero resistance and then you are dividing 5V/50ohm to obtain 100mA current just like you take coax resistance into account like a usual resistor. something is foggy in my mind here

Comment: @user16307, when voltage is first applied to the 50 Ohm cable, it looks like a 50 Ohm resistor UNTIL the reflection comes back from the far end. If the cable is infinitely long, or if it is terminated in 50 Ohms, then no reflection comes back, and it is a true 50 Ohm load. The signal, and the reflection, travel at the "speed of light," however, they travel in the dielectric of the cable, so the speed of light will be less than speed of light in vacuum.

Comment: Nice animations but a bit misleading. Open end will actually increase the voltage on the 1st reflection as your diagram correctly shows. This was used in anger with the venerable PCI bus where they boosted voltage from 3.3V to 5V by using reflections.

Comment: @mkeith The more peculiar it becomes the more I dig it. It it is like a approaching to a tornado. you wrote "when voltage is first applied to the 50 Ohm cable, it looks like a 50 Ohm resistor UNTIL the reflection comes back from the far end." and Andy Aka writes current will flow until it reaches to 1k Ohm. How can current flow without a complete loop. Aren't electrons in a wire having the same push distance at the same time?

Comment: @user16307 please read about transmission line theory. Also, please read about the "lumped element approximation" of transmission lines. As Andy said, transmission lines have capacitance and inductance. Since they have capacitance, current from the source can flow immediately, even though that current does not reach the load immediately.

Comment: @user16307 "Transmission line theory" is kind of tall order to read. If you're really interested, Eric Bogatin has written quite easy-to-understand textbook on the matter, "Signal integrity - Simplified". He works by examples by imagining you're "the signal" going down the wire which is a fair bit easier to grasp for most people than equations.

Comment: @Barleyman - misleading - can you elaborate?

Comment: @user16307 there is a great video on youtube which uses a mechanical model of the transmission line. I'll try and find it. Here I believe: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DovunOxlY1k. It's a 30 min video but worth the watch. The Shive wave machine!

Comment: great I also found another retro video very cool: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I9m2w4DgeVk

Comment: Just one last question: Imagine we have a very sharp pulse train but only 50Hz freq. and we have 50cm short coax cable. 50Hz has huge wave length we can conclude we don't need matching because our cable is 50cm much less than the wavelength where no reflection occurs. But if we think the high freq. components of the pulse we might have reflection. Is that right? So in case same signal is not a pulse but a pure sine, we don't need matching at all but in case of sharp pulse we need because it has ultra high freq. components which might reflect due to their short wavelength? Did I understand it?

Comment: You did understand it and if the 50 Hz pulse train was actual data there could still be corruptions around the points where the data changes state. Of course if the top data rate was only 50 Hz then simple filters would remove any trace of anything that would corrupt data receivers but generally a terminator wouldn't be used. RS232 transmits quite happily at several kbaud without a terminator for instance. We also need terminators with sinewaves - you can get standing waves without a properly terminated line and these can be problematic. Power reflections into a transmitter can destoy it.

Comment: @Andyaka Misleading in the sense that the animated gif has the pulse reflected as is. In reality it reflects on top of the original signal causing issues. As your other diagram shows.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link explaining the "50 ohm" history:
http://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/why-fifty-ohms

That, as well as 75 ohm, most likely were settled on by early coaxial cable manufacturers dictated by manufacturing issues.

For what it's worth, there's nothing "magic" about either. But as the article will tell you, 50 ohm is a very good match on a coaxial cable of a certain construction. On a PCB you could use whatever as long as it a) does allow for your rise/fall times to happen and b) does not overwhelm your driver.

Comment: I found this might be a good introduction to the topic: http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-14/50-ohm-cable/ eventhough in their switch lamp example they don't take into account the special theory of relativity when it comes to cause effect observation.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I9m2w4DgeVk

Comment: @user16307 there are a lot of resources for signal integrity but that microwave article explains the origin of those values. PTFE was invented only after 50 ohm cable was settled on..